# How to Browse API docs - specific case of Sequencer interface

Tags: java

I wanted to create a Sequencer object for a MIDI hobby/learning project. Now Sequencer is an Interface so the way i can get to use the methods defined in Sequencer is to try instantiating a class that implements Sequencer interface and assign it to Sequencer reference. Now here is the problem!

ie. `Sequencer sequencer = new <Someclass that implements Sequencer?>`

But check the API docs for java9.0 and there are no implementing classes for Sequencer Interface! Now what to do?

Googling the question resulted in the answer:

```
Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
```

Now MidiSystem does not even implements this interface Sequencer.

In short:

I just want to know what you do(how you proceed) when you need an object to assign to an interface but don't have any implementing sub-classes, like in the above case, cause there must be a more straightforward way than google search.

Comment: The fact that `MidiSystem.getSequencer()` returns a `Sequencer` and the fact that `MidiSystem` doesn't implement the `Sequencer` interface are completely orthogonal, so that should not surprise you.

Comment: Also, not all APIs allow you to instantiate objects by calling their constructors. Some (like this, apparently) have factory methods that return the correct object without you having to decide which is the correct one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes so getSequencer() is a factory method, but my question still is how do you discover this method without someone telling you? cause there is no relation between getSequencer() and Seqencer() you may end up browsing 6006 odd classes for that or searching all the suggestions thrown in API Search window, is this how usually programmers proceed in such situations?

Comment: Usually by reading the [official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/overview-MIDI.html).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ok, thanks. I was carrying an impression that there is a on-the-fly way of coding where you just look up API and it will tell you everything there is to know about its usage, well in this case it was not the case.